# matching the ls command output

Tags: c, ls

I'm trying to code the ls command. I have the following function that prints each file name :

```
int ft_list(const char *filename)
{
    DIR *dirp;
    struct dirent *dir;

    if (!(dirp = opendir(filename)))
        return (-1);
    while ((dir = readdir(dirp)))
    {
        if (dir->d_name[0] != '.')
            ft_putendl(dir->d_name);
    }
    closedir(dirp);
    return (0);
}
```

The ls command prints the files organized into columns to fit the screen width. I have read about it and I think it uses the `ioctl` standard library function, but I can't find any details. How exactly can I do this?

Comment: Have you looked at the help for ioctl?

Comment: i have read the man but still i don't understand how to use it or how it works

Comment: Can you show the usage of ioctl and the bad behavior?

Comment: my output is like 'ls - 1' command , and for the usage you can google it , it's long to copy

Comment: *it uses the input output control ioctl* that's a novel idea, unfortunately, with no basis in reality.

Comment: @n.m.: Basis in reality: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=blob;f=src/ls.c;h=bf0c5941d7de699fc5a85d44461ef29192216d9d;hb=HEAD#l1755

Comment: @rici ugh, it just didn't occur to me that "in organised way" has something to do with its tabular output. ls -1 doesn't do tabular output. I assumed OP meant that the output is sorted. My apologies.

Comment: @n.m.: yeah, the language was a bit obscure. I edited the question to try to make it more clear, but not in time to avoid yet another close- and down-vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to arrange the files in columns, you need to figure out the current width of the terminal window. On many unix-like systems (including Linux and OS X), you can indeed use `ioctl` to get that information, using the `TIOCGWINSZ` selector.

This is precisely what `ls` does (on systems which support the `ioctl` request), once it has determined that standard output is a terminal (unless single-column firmat is forced with the `-1` flag). If it cannot figure out the terminal width, it uses 80.

Here's a quick example of how to get the information. (On Linux systems, you can probably find the details by typing `man tty_ioctl`).

For simplicity, the following code assumes that `stdout` is file descriptor 1. In retrospect, `FILE_STDOUT` would have been better. If you wanted to check an arbitrary open file, you would need to use `fileno` to get the fd number for the `FILE*`.

```
/* This must come before any include, in order to see the
 * declarations of Posix functions which are not in standard C
 */
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

/* If stdout is a terminal and it is possible to find out how many
 * columns its window has, return that number. Otherwise, return -1
 */
int window_get_columns(void) {
  struct winsize sizes;
  int cols = -1;
  if (isatty(1)) { 
    /* Only try this if stdout is a terminal */
    int status = ioctl(1, TIOCGWINSZ, &sizes);
    if (status == 0) {
      cols = sizes.ws_col;
    }
  }
  return cols;
}

/* Example usage */

/* Print a line consisting of 'len' copies of the character 'ch' */
void print_row(int len, int ch) {
  for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) putchar(ch);
  putchar('\n');
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  /* Print the first argument centred in the terminal window,
   * if standard output is a terminal
   */
  if (argc <= 1) return 1; /* No argument, nothing to do */
  int width = window_get_columns();
  /* If we can't figure out the width of the screen, just use the
   * width of the string
   */
  int arglen = strlen(argv[1]);
  if (width < 0) width = arglen;
  int indent = (width - arglen) / 2;
  print_row(width - 1, '-');
  printf("%*s\n", indent + arglen, argv[1]);
  print_row(width - 1, '-');
  return 0;
}
```

Since writing the above sample, I tracked down the source of the Gnu implementation of `ls`; its (somewhat more careful) invocation of `ioctl` will be seen [here](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=blob;f=src/ls.c;h=bf0c5941d7de699fc5a85d44461ef29192216d9d;hb=HEAD#l1755)